# What should I include in a Python source distribution?

Tags: python, package, setuptools

What files should I include in the source distribution of my Python package? I understand that all the modules must be in the package, and according to the default includes, all tests should be there as well, but should I include things like my `.gitignore`, `MANIFEST.in` or `setup.py`?

Comment: Certainly not `.gitignore`, as the source distribution is not connected to your Git repo. `MANIFEST.in` and `setup.py` are included automatically. Your license, readme, and [changelog](http://keepachangelog.com/) (if any) are probably good candidates. But I’m not aware of any explicit best practices here.

Comment: Following common practice found on the net, I always included almost everything in Python packages: docs, tests, scripts, configuration files, etc. Now I think it's unnecessary, because: I never ran tests of an installed packages, and I never use the installed docs. So now I include the source code only and the markdown documents like readme, changelog, contributing and license. That's all.